# Where does Aptana store temporary FTP files?

Tags: windows-7, ftp, aptana, aptana3

I'm using an Aptana Studio 3 FTP Connection (on Win7) to directly edit files on my server, without a local copy. On save, Aptana seems to store a temp file (`home.php._tmp_uploadphp`), and then uploads it to the server and renames it to the correct file (`home.php`) after deleting the stale remote copy.

I'm trying to find the local folder that Aptana saves the temp file in prior to uploading it. Does anyone know if these files are saved to the local filesystem and then deleted immediately after upload, or if they're possibly just stored in memory and upped directly.

I've checked the entire drive and it is nowhere to be found, so it seems to be creating and then deleting it immediately after.

Thanks

Comment: It's a temp file "belonging" to Aptana (if it exists at all) - what would you do with this information?

Comment: I want to watch that folder for changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Aptana Studio 3.1.3 and after, the local copy is saved under aptanavfs/ of the system temp directory, or what the "java.io.tmpdir" variable is pointing to (e.g. on Linux, it'd be /tmp/aptanavfs/); in 3.1.2 and before, all files were saved directly under the temp directory. The files will be deleted when you exit Studio.

Here is the reference [ticket](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3565).